# Oracle SQL Developer running commands and seeing output

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I create new connection in oracle SQL, then try to this query but don't why isn't running

Here the query:
[image]

I click run statement but it show nothing.

I select all the query and click run and try the shortcut also nothing showed

Comment: Looks like you **opened** a .SQL file. But, did you **establish connection**? You said you created one (which is OK), but - are you actually connected to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't running a query, you're running a command.

And your results panel is collapsed. Drag this up.

[image]

Then you should see script output with feedback from running your ALTER USER command.